# Using Manifest.js & config.assets.precompile in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I was trying to understand the difference between these two things, `manifest.js` and `config.assets.precompile` in `application.rb`

When we want to use some specific CSS or js for a page, we usually add that into the `config.assets.precompile` and include that JS/CSS in the page using (`javascript_include_tag` or `stylesheet_link_tag`). If we wanted to use any CSS or js at the global level, then we are adding under the application.js or application.css

Recently I have seen `manifest.js`, so instead of adding the files under `config.assets.precompile`, add that in the manifest.js and include it in the specific page where we need that. So what would be the difference? Which one can we use it?